# Basic task to make square of stars with for statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a square of stars using `for` loop. It is not even close to what I'm trying to do.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
number = int(input())

for i in range(number):
    for j in range(number):
        if i == 0 or i == number - 1 or j == 0 or j == number - 1:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print("", end=" ")
            print()
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

[image]

I also don't get why the stars on the first row are 6 when my input number is 5 even though I put `num-1` in the `if` statement.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post code (and output) as text, not images of text.

Comment: Check your indentations.

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop like:

```
for i in range(number):
    if i < 1 or i >= number - 1:
        print('*' * number)
    else:
        print('*' + ' ' * (number - 2) + '*')
```

I get output like:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

for `number = 5` and

```
***************
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
*             *
***************
```

for `number = 15`

Were your nested for-loops indented correctly?